# Is there any way to do java compilation and deployment to web server inside the docker container?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, tomcat9

Is there any way to do java compilation and deployment to web server inside the docker container?

I'm not able to pull both JDK image and Tomcat Server images in single Dockerfile, is there any alternative to address this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is too general and it is related to the basic concept of building docker images.

However, a simple answer for this could be having open JDK as a base image and then install the tomcat server manually.

Comment: The [Docker Official Images](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat) for Tomcat are based on a JDK image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you have write a **multistage docker file** as explained here https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/ and here https://mailslurp.medium.com/faster-java-containers-with-docker-multi-stage-builds-cc63e056e546 .

Follow and example from the last postd link:

```
# build stage build the jar with all our resources
FROM openjdk:8-jdk as build

ARG VERSION
ARG JAR_PATH

VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /
ADD . .

RUN ./gradlew --stacktrace clean test build
RUN mv /$JAR_PATH /app.jar

# package stage
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /
# copy only the built jar and nothing else
COPY --from=build /app.jar /

ENV VERSION=$VERSIOsN
ENV JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.profiles.active=production

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production /app.jar"]
```

Obviously you have to customized it as per your needs.